# ¿Cómo hacer que aparezca un botón para ejecutar una actualización después de presentarla?

Tags: php, html

```html
<body>
    <div id="content" class="padding-20">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="pedirdatos">
                <div class="row">
                            <div id="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                <label>Informe </label>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" 
                                       name="file1" id="file1" enabled
                                       onchange="documentocargado()" 
                                       style="width:100%"/>
                </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-12">
                   <input type="submit" name="mostrar" class="btn btn-success"
                                style="margin-top:26px;" value=" Consultar "  
                                onclick="comprueba();" 
                                onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
                  </div>
(este es el submit que no debe aparecer de inicio)
                   <input type="submit" id="mostrar" name="mostrar" position= 
                   "relative" top = "20x" class="btn btn-success" disabled
                    onclick="actualizo();"  value=" Actualizar 
                    registros? " onchange="this.form.submit()"  >  
                   </div>

                   <div class="panel-body" 
                            id="mostrardatos"style="display:none">
                   <table width='100%' id='tabla1' 
                          class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                   </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```html
 ...       if (file_exists($ficherofinal))
    { 
      $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
      $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($ficherofinal);
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
      $numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
      foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
       {  
      for ($i = 9; $i <= $numRows; $i++) 
       {
       $serie = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
      $albaran = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
      $fechafac = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
      $referencia = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
      echo    "<tr>" .
          "<td>" . $serie . "</td>" .
          "<td>" . $albaran . "</td>" .
          "<td>" . $fechafac  . "</td>" .
          "<td>" . $referencia  . "</td>" .
          "</tr>";   
            } } } }

          ?>
                    (aqui es donde se llama a la funcion que actualiza datos)
          <script languaje='JavaScript' type = 'text/JavaScript' > activa()</script>
                             </tbody>
       <tfoot> ....
```

Estoy creando una aplicación en `HTML` y `PHP`, y tengo un problema.
El caso es que al entrar en una consulta, esta me pide un excel para leer, del cual sacaré los datos para actualizar la base de datos....
Pero quiero que el programa lleve una secuencia concreta ...

1. Pedir fichero a leer del disco.
2. Confirmarlo.
3. Presentar la información que tiene dicho fichero.
4. Que aparezca un botón que pida la confirmación de la actualización de los datos presentados.

Vengo de programar en Visual y la secuencia del `html` se me escapa un poco..., he llegado a pedir el fichero y presentarlo, pero la parte de presentar el botón de conformación no llego a sacarlo.

¿Me podéis aportar alguna idea acerca de este problema?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Si te es posible comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible para tu caso concreto.

Comment: Ya esta echo ..

Comment: sigues necesitando ayuda con esto?

Comment: si .. Todavia o lo he encontrado